# Conditional return values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

I have started a simple auction system where each row contains the following data:

```
Type:= BID|WIT
ProductName := Str
User := Str
Value := Decimal
CreatedAt := datetime
```

*Here WIT means **withdraw**, aka quit from item auction *

A user can naturally do multiple bid requests, always raising the bid value (this is handled at language level)

I would like to list all top bids from all users but under a condition, only if they are not before a WITHDRAW request for the given item.

For example, given the entries

```
BID,Doll,John,10,2021-11-26 10:10
BID,Ball,John,12,2021-11-26 10:11
BID,Doll,Mary,12,2021-11-26 10:12
BID,Doll,Alice,13,2021-11-26 10:13
BID,Doll,Mary,14,2021-11-26 10:14
BID,Doll,Alice,17,2021-11-26 10:14
BID,Ball,Mary,14,2021-11-26 10:14
WIT,Doll,John,00,2021-11-26 10:16
BID,Doll,Mary,20,2021-11-26 10:18
BID,Ball,John,15,2021-11-26 10:20
```

If I `magic_sql_query(Doll)` I would like to get

```
BID,Doll,Alice,17,2021-11-26 10:14
BID,Doll,Mary,20,2021-11-26 10:18
```

Also If I `magic_sql_query(Ball)` I would like to get:

```
BID,Ball,Mary,14,2021-11-26 10:14
BID,Ball,John,15,2021-11-26 10:20
```

How can I do it in a SQL Statement?

Comment: Left join BIDs to WITs to get withdrawal timestamp. Row_number() not withdrawn BIDs.

Comment: Heya @Serg do you mind write a more complete answer? I'm still trying to understand everything.

Comment: See the answer, @Lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

- use the `row_number()` windowing function to rank within a group (a
  group is defined by the username and the product); the latest entry
  gets rank 1
- get rid of all entries whose rank is > 1 (i.e. the user has a later entry for this product)
- get rid of all entries of type 'WIT'

```
    with base as (select
      b.type, 
      b.productname, 
      b.username,
      b.value,
      b.createdat,
      row_number() over (partition by productname, username 
                         order by createdat desc) as rn
      from bids b
      order by productname, username, createdat
    )
    select * from base
    where rn = 1
    and type = 'BID';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b3aa3/5)

Comment: wouldn't `order_by value` be more "auction correct"?

Comment: @Lin Since a withdrawal has a value of 0, sorting by value wouldn't be correct. But you're right - sorting by createdat works only if the system prevents users from entering a lower bid at a later point in time. To account for network glitches / out-of-order entries in the system, something more sophisticated would be required.

Answer (score 0):

To find all bids that have no withdrawal later (by the same user for the same product) you can use a NOT EXITS condition:

```
select a1.*
where a1.product_name = 'Ball'
  and type = 'BID'
  and not exists (select *
                  from auction a2
                  where a2.product_name = a1.product_name
                    and a2.user_name = a1.user_name
                    and a2.type = 'WIT' 
                    and a2.created_at > a1.created_at)
```

Now we need to filter out the highest bids per product and user. This can be done using the `dense_rank()` function.

```
select type, product_name, user_name, value, created_at
from (
  select a1.*, dense_rank() over (partition by product_name, user_name order by value desc) as rnk
  from auction a1
  where a1.product_name = 'Ball'
    and type = 'BID'
    and not exists (select *
                    from auction a2
                    where a2.product_name = a1.product_name
                      and a2.user_name = a1.user_name
                      and a2.type = 'WIT' 
                      and a2.created_at > a1.created_at)
) t
where rnk = 1
order by created_at;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69ec0f5f1cb47660953a92ef324d092b)

Comment: the use of `rank` or `dense_rank` here makes no difference correct?

Comment: @Lin: it makes a difference if you have bids with the same value

Answer (score 0):

A left join version

```
select t.Type, product_name, t.User, Value, CreatedAt
from (
    select b.*
      , row_number() over(partition by b.product_name, b.user order by b.createdAt desc) rn
    from auction b
    left join auction w
    on w.type = 'WIT' 
       and b.product_name = w.product_name
       and b.user = w.user
       and w.createdAt > b.createdAt
    where b.type = 'BID' 
       and w.product_name is null
       -- and b.product_name = 'Ball'
) t
where rn=1
   -- and product_name = 'Ball'
order by product_name, CreatedAt;
```

uncomment one of `.. product_name = 'Ball'` to get only this product.

[db<>fidlle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7250e37978bf7ee20104572cc30121cf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` window function to get for each user the last entry with `type = 'BID'` and the last entry with `type = 'WIT'`.
Then filter the results:

```
SELECT type, productname, "user", value, createdat
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'BID' THEN createdat END) OVER (PARTITION BY "user") last_bid,
         MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'WIT' THEN createdat END) OVER (PARTITION BY "user") last_wit
  FROM tablename
  WHERE productname = ?
) t
WHERE (last_wit IS NULL OR last_wit < last_bid) AND createdat = last_bid;
```

Replace `?` with the name of the product that you want.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ef75395162d848c2bc83acef4bd32dc).